# Set page size to all on load on a kendo grid

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have a simple question I cannot seem to find the answer to. I would like the grid to default to show all results on load. If possible even take out the paging at the bottom but I cannot seem to find it anywhere.

This is my grid:

```
 @(Html.Kendo().Grid<Website.Models.LinesForPayType.LinesForPayTypeGridModel>()
    .Name("gridAssignLines")        
    .ToolBar(toolbar =>
    {
        toolbar.Create().HtmlAttributes(new { @id = "CreatePaymentTypeLine", @style = "display:inline-block;" });
        toolbar.Save().SaveText("Create Invoice").HtmlAttributes(new { id = "create-invoice", href = "#" }); ;
    })
    .Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Select().Width(30);
        columns.Bound(c => c.Description);
        columns.Bound(c => c.LineNo);
        columns.Bound(c => c.Quantity);
        columns.Bound(c => c.UnitPrice)
        .ClientTemplate(Model.HomeCurrencySymbol + " #=kendo.toString(UnitPrice ? UnitPrice : 0,'n2')#");
        columns.Bound(c => c.Total)
        .ClientTemplate(Model.HomeCurrencySymbol + " #=kendo.toString(Total ? Total : 0,'n2')#");
    })
    .Events(e => e.DataBound("AddStudentController.onCheckClick"))
    .Pageable(page => page
        .Refresh(true)
        .PageSizes("All")
        )
    .Editable(edit => edit.Mode(GridEditMode.InCell))
    .Scrollable()
    .Events(events => events.Save("AddStudentController.onInvoiceGridSave"))
    .Reorderable(reorder => reorder.Columns(true))
    .NoRecords("No data")
    .Filterable(f => f.Operators(o => o.ForString(fs => fs.Clear().Contains("Contains").StartsWith("Start With").EndsWith("End with").IsEqualTo("Is equal to").IsNotEqualTo("Is not equal to"))))
    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
    .Ajax()
    .ServerOperation(true)
    .Sort(s =>
    {
        s.Add(a => a.LineNo).Ascending();
    })
    .Model(model =>
    {
        model.Id(i => i.ID);
    })
    .Read(read => read.Action("ReadPaymentTypeLines", "Payment").Data("AddStudentController.getPaymentTypeID"))
    .Create(create => create.Action("CreatePaymentTypeLines", "Payment"))
    .Update(update => update.Action("CreatePaymentTypeLines", "Payment"))
    )
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Set the datasource's `PageSize` to `int.MaxValue` (e.g. https://docs.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/api/Kendo.Mvc.UI.Fluent/GridBuilder#datasourcesystemstring) and if you don't want to see the paging stuff, set `Pageable` to `false`.

Comment: Sorry, this was not the correct answer to the problem so I can't mark it as correct. I removed the `Pageable`. But the problem was in my code, I completely forgot I had a grid resize method which again sets the number of rows according to size.